# Need Help to Translate Please

Tags: translation, simplified-characters, traditional-characters

[image: Notes under a mouse]

Kindly help me translate these notes under a mouse :-)

Comment: I am skeptical about your intention hum... This is the same handwriting as that in your last question. I am wondering why you don't just ask the writer?

Comment: And you label the question with both simplified and traditional Chinese, which means you don't have any idea of or you ve put no effort into it.

Comment: question submitted to https://bkrs.info/taolun/thread-314961.html

Answer (score 3):

Tuesday night:

1. Fry two chicken legs (add a few drops of oyster sauce)
2. Egg fried rice
3. 10 beef balls